# increment++ is adding 4 instead of 1 Objective C Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, increment

I have just started the Stanford Course Building a card game "Machismo"
I have the following code which builds and runs great but my label in the corner that tracks the card flipping over increments by 4 instead of 1. Help!

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipsLabel;
@property (nonatomic) int *flipCount;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController

- (void) setFlipCount:(int *) flipCount {
    _flipCount = flipCount;
    self.flipsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d", (int) self.flipCount];
}

    enter code here
- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([sender.currentTitle length]) { 
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"] 
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:@"A♣︎" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    self.flipCount++;  // << HERE IS THE INCREMENT <<

}


@end
```

Answer (score 4):

You are incrementing a pointer (which is incremented by the size of the pointee, and sizeof(int) == 4 in your case) and casting it to int for printing. You should be incrementing an int instead.